# How to get an agent to face the direction of travel when strafing around a target? (Unity / C#)

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I am developing a FPS game in Unity and I am wanting to have an agent (an animated bat) strafe around a target.
Everything works fine, but the bat is facing a fixed direction instead of facing the direction of travel as it strafes around the target.
I have tried adding a Quaternion rotation as per the code listed below (see 'Face in the right direction') but to no avail. I have commented out sections of code to see if I can identify where the issue lies, but that just cause more issues.
Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Code...

```
// Target position. The gameobject will circle around this position.
[SerializeField]
private Vector3 TargetPosition = new Vector3();

// Temp Position. Used to generate a new position on the circle.
private Vector3 tempPosition = new Vector3();

// Radius. Generated from the game objects current distance to the target.
float r;

// The current angle in the circle strafe.
float theta;

/// movement variables
private Vector3 currentTargetPos; 

// Start is called before the first frame update
void Start()
{
    // Get the radius. The distance to the target position.
    r = Vector3.Distance(transform.position, TargetPosition);

    // Default theta.
    theta = Mathf.Acos((transform.position.x - TargetPosition.x) / r);

    // Check quadrant and adjust.
    if ((transform.position.x - TargetPosition.x) > 0 &&
                        (transform.position.y - TargetPosition.y) > 0)
    {
        Debug.Log("Quadrant 1");
    }
    if ((transform.position.x - TargetPosition.x) < 0 &&
    (transform.position.y - TargetPosition.y) > 0)
    {
        Debug.Log("Quadrant 2");
    }
    if ((transform.position.x - TargetPosition.x) < 0 &&
                        (transform.position.y - TargetPosition.y) < 0)
    {
        Debug.Log("Quadrant 3");
        theta = -theta;
    }
    if ((transform.position.x - TargetPosition.x) > 0 &&
                        (transform.position.y - TargetPosition.y) < 0)
    {
        Debug.Log("Quadrant 4");
        theta = -theta;
    }
    Debug.Log("theta x = " + theta);
}
// Update is called once per frame
void Update()
{
    // Get the actors circle strafe location.
    tempPosition.x = TargetPosition.x + r * Mathf.Cos(theta);
    tempPosition.z = TargetPosition.z + r * Mathf.Sin(theta);
    tempPosition.y = transform.position.y;

    // Update t.
    theta += 0.2f * Time.deltaTime;

    // Set the location.
    transform.position = tempPosition;

    // clear y to avoid up/down movement
    currentTargetPos.y = transform.position.y; 

    Vector3 direction = currentTargetPos - transform.position;

    // face in the right direction
    direction.y = 0;
    Quaternion rotation = Quaternion.LookRotation(-direction, Vector3.up);
    transform.rotation = rotation;
}

// Draws debug objects in the editor and during editor play (if option set).
void OnDrawGizmos()
{
    // Draw target position.
    Gizmos.color = Color.red;
    Gizmos.DrawSphere(TargetPosition, 0.2f);
}
```

}

Comment: The name of `currentTargetPos` is a little misleading to me but what if you do `currentTargetPos = transform.position;` immediately before the `transform.position = tempPosition;` line? You never seem to set its x or z components.  Also, you don't need the `currentTargetPos.y = transform.position.y;` line this way

Comment: @Ruzihm Thank you so much. This worked flawlessly! I am forever grateful.

Answer (score 0):

Unity has a built-in function for transforms called `LookAt()` that takes a `Transform other` or `Vector3 worldPosition` as a parameter. To implement it, you can write `transform.LookAt(TargetPosition)`.

Note that this may impact translations that rely on local rotation, so if you have problems you’ll need to change some logic as well. To circumvent this you may want to reset the rotation before moving, then moving the rotation back to where it needs to be, or better by using world space instead of local space.

Comment: Thanks. I forgot to mention, I had tried this already, but the issue remains.